# Efficient collection of all (great) grand children of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a team model that looks like this:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applications
  has_many :interests, through: :applications
  has_many :indications, through: :interests
end
```

I have an Indication model that looks like this:

```
class Indication < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :interest
   belongs_to :application
   belongs_to :team

   scope :open, -> {where(selection_stages_id: nil, selection_statuses_id: nil)}

end
```

I can see a use case where I might have a collection of multiple teams and I would like to have a collection of all indications that could be linked with them.

```
  ####example
  teams = Team.all
  associated_indications = teams.collect(&:indications)
  # => [#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Indication id: 1, selection_stages_id: nil, selection_statuses_id: nil, interest_id: 2, created_at: "2016-07-26 23:51:36", updated_at: "2016-07-27 15:20:12">]>] 

   ### I would like to do this:
   #1# associated_indications.find(1)
   # ==> #<Enumerator: [#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Indication id: 1, selection_stages_id: nil, selection_statuses_id: nil, interest_id: 2, created_at: "2016-07-26 23:51:36", updated_at: "2016-07-27 15:20:12">]>]:find(1)> 
   #2# associated_indications.include?(Indication.find(1))
   # ==> false


 #for comparison, 
 Team.all.find(1).indications
 # ==> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Indication id: 1, selection_stages_id: nil, selection_statuses_id: nil, interest_id: 2, created_at: "2016-07-26 23:51:36", updated_at: "2016-07-27 15:20:12">]>
 # This following line throws an error
 Team.all.indications
 # ^ Holy Grail
```

Any ideas? If you made it this far, I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
teams = Team.all
indications = Indication.joins(interest: { application: :team }).where(teams: { id: teams.pluck(:id) })
```

It's just 2 queries, and indication is still a ActiveRecord Relation.

Comment: I have added a response to my main question.  It's my first time executing 'joins' and 'pluck'!

Comment: You don't have to add it to your response, once we find a solution that works for you, you simply mark it. That `joins` is failing becuase Indication doesn't belong to team as you indicated, at least not directly. `Indication.find(1).team` fails right?

Comment: I've updated my response, guessing how the rest of relations are set in Interest.rb and Application.rb

Comment: Yes, as does Indication.find(1).application.

Comment: That did the trick! I rolled back my question and marked your response with the green check.  Anything else that would be useful for me to do?

Comment: Next time, just be as explicit as you can from the beginning with your question, in this case having `Interest` from the beginning would had help. A tip: usually, in Rails, you start your "query" with the model you want to get back. If you want to get back indications, you start with `Indication` and join whatever you have to, to narrow it down.